# Does Paw.app include support for sending HTTP requests to UNIX sockets?

Tags: paw-app

Does Paw.app support sending HTTP requests to UNIX sockets similar to `curl --unix-socket=/tmp/my.sock`?

Thanks!

-- 
-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, this isn't supported by Paw. Maybe later :) It should be doable as we have our own HTTP library. The limitations of OS X sandboxing may limit this, but we can find workarounds…

Comment: FYI, here was my workaround as I presented it to a colleague. "Paw is amazing @vladimirvivien. One thing on which it does fall short? No posting to UNIX sockets. However, using `brew install socat` and then `socat TCP-LISTEN:7981,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/tmp/libstorage.sock`, you can easily forward all TCP traffic for the port 7981 to the sock file that the libStorage test suite configures for the libStorage server."

Comment: Nice workaround! :) We should add this to our documentation!

Comment: Did anything have changed since 2016? Still no support for UNIX sockets?